# Java USES HTTP v1 to send Chinese notifications that are error characters

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

The request header is the same as the official document. Why did android receive the wrong character when I used Chinese? Using English is correct

```
private HttpURLConnection getConnections() throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(BASE_URL + FCM_SEND_ENDPOINT);
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + getAccessTokens());
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; UTF-8");
    return httpURLConnection;
}
```